# Marginal Density vs Probability Density

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

So for my weekly homework assignment for my probability class, there is a question that I am unsure about.

Typically, a question usually begins with something along the lines of "Suppose X and Y are random variables with joint density..." and asks to find something along the lines of "find the marginal density of X."

Now that's all fine and good; it's easy enough to do. What i'm confused about is a similar question that begins in a similar fashion, but instead asks "find the probability density function of X."

My main concern is this: is there a difference between the marginal density and probability density? are they the same thing? It is confusing because the question still involves a joint density function of X and Y.

If there is a need for clarification on my question let me know and i'll try to create an example that is not my exact homework problem because that wouldn't encourage my learning.

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that the probability distribution is allowed to depend on y.

Comment: Meanwhile, without other information, I would guess the probability distribution for $X$ was its marginal distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a random vector $(X, Y)$ then its joint density is a function of two arguments connected with joint probability function $\text{Pr} (X \leq x, Y \leq y)$.

But if you know the joint density of $(X, Y)$ you're able to compute the density of $X$ or $Y$  themselves - these densities of single variables are called marginal ones.